# iOS interface builder constraints - what is this red square

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints

I've added a constraint to a label with greater or equal from bottom of container.

When i'm modifying the screen height, the label doesn't move, but instead there is this red square showing me where the label should have been according to the constraint:

[image: screenshot]

What is this square and why doesn't my label move according to the constraint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on tiny red baloon next to your view hierarchy's "Create Album View" .

Then it will show a list of issue/ conflict in your constraints.

Click the tiny red/orange baloons next to each issue and select appropriate option. Such as "Update constraints" , or "Rest to suggested constraints" to fix issues.

Comment: i've done it, and fixed it, but yet every time i resize the screen the same issue is poping out

Comment: that's because you are only changing the frame, without updating constraints. Red bounding box shows where would your control actually be placed in run time. Whenever you drag controls in your IB, it will not update constraints automatically. You have to manually do it.

Comment: so how come when i'm adding space from left to the superview, and resizing the frame it does shows ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of constraints you have. If you changed some constraints which does not depend on any other constraint, it would show. But if you change a constraint which is affected by other constraints , then there will be a conflict and would not show the change automatically in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't added complete constraints, Added only vertical constraints(constraint to a label with greater or equal from bottom of container), but horizontal constraints is not added w.r.t Superview. For more information on resolving constraints refer [Resolving Auto Layout Issues](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ResolvingIssues/ResolvingIssues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW1)

Comment: that weird because when i added a constraint from the left of the screen and resized it - it did changed

Comment: @AsafNevo You didn't added complete constraints, Added only Y constraints , X constraints is not added.

Comment: I must say i don't really getting it

Comment: @AsafNevo please go through Apple doc link to understand clearly.